# How to add an slider bar into QMenu?

Tags: qt

My context menu have so many items that i need a slider bar to control it, but i did't find any function could do this. How could i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menus don't have scrollbars. The style and behavior of (context) menus is defined by OS X, Windows, KDE/Gnome etc., and to my knowledge none of them include scrollbars. Sometimes the menu wraps if it doesn't fit the screen, which is already annoying. Scrollbars in a context menu would be even more unusable. 
A context menu is just not the right place for such a huge amount of items, and you should redesign your application accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

From another thread on Stack Overflow, I found this trick:

```
submenu->setStyleSheet("QMenu { menu-scrollable: 1; }");
```

For further information, see [create a scrollbar in a submenu qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121718/create-a-scrollbar-in-a-submenu-qt)

@Frank Osterfeld: I have a perfect example of a valid use case for huge contextual menu that needs a scrollbar, Qt Creator and the auto-completion list.