# create a scrollbar in a submenu qt?

Tags: c++, qt, menu, scrollbar

I have a map application and a submenu which has dynamically added objects (i.e. points on a map) added to the submenu, depending on the layer that is loaded.  I have the ability to hide each individual objects (i.e. a point) by clicking on the corresponding submenu item.  Is there any way to organize the submenu?  When there are a lot of points (i.e. 100) the entire submenu takes up the screen.  Can I add a scrollbar to a submenu?  I looked in the documentation, but couldn't find anything that support this feature.

Answer (score 15):

From [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-5103) I was able to find out that you could do the following:

```
submenu->setStyleSheet("QMenu { menu-scrollable: 1; }");
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: This appears to have stopped working in Qt 6 (it does not work for me in Qt 6.4).  What does work is creating a custom `QProxyStyle` and setting the sub-menu's style to it.  See the example in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproxystyle.html#details (but return true on the `QStyle::SH_Menu_Scrollable` hint - also, `QWidget::setStyle` does not transfer ownership, so their example has a memory leak)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility as far as I know.
Maybe you shouldn't use a sub menu for this but prefer a menu entry that show a Point manager GUI of your own which would have a QListWidget displaying all your points items.
I'm aware that this solution will break a (big?) part of your code but I don't see anything else.

Comment: So basically create a popup instead of a submenu to manage all the objects?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to get the effect you want by creating and using your own QStyle subclass (via QApplication::setStyle()), and overriding the styleHint virtual method to return 1 when the StyleHint parameter passed in is SH_Menu_Scrollable.  At least, that works for me when I create large QMenu objects and show them as popup menus.... It may also work for QMenus attached to the menu bar, but I havent tried that.

Answer (score -1):

Whilst it is possible by subclassing the QMenu class to create a custom widget and going from there you're better off looking at a better way to display that information. You'll save yourself time and it'll be much easier for your users to not have to scroll through a big list of items in a small area.